# How to prevent object creation in __init__() python

Tags: python, oop, init

Am practicing python OOP with TDD. The following code is creating an object of class office of subclass room even when given a name starting with a digit. How do I prevent it? Thanks guys for help

```
class Room(object):

    """Create general features of a general room
    Each room has a certain capacity depending on its type(an office or a living room)
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(Room, self).__init__()
        self.capacity = '';

class Office(Room):

    """
    Add specific features to make a room an office.
    An office has a name and a space for maximum of 4 people.
    """

    def __init__(self, rname):

        #create object if name does not start with a digit
        if not (rname[0].isdigit()):
            super(Office,self).__init__()
            self.name = rname #office name
            self.capacity = 4 #number of spaces per office
```

Here is the testcase:

```
class OfficeTests(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.office = Office('BLUE')
    self.office1 = Office('12345')

def test_office_is_of_class_office(self):
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(self.office, Office), 
       msg = "Should create      an object of class Office")

def test_office_is_of_class_room(self):
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(self.office, Room), 
        msg = "Should create an object of class Office of subclass Room")

def test_office_capacity_is_4(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.office.capacity, 4, 
          msg= "An office has a maximum of 4 ")

def test_office_has_a_name(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.office.name,'BLUE', msg = "Should assign name to an office created.")

def test_office_name_does_not_start_with_a_digit(self):
    print(self.office1, self.office)
    self.assertTrue(self.office1 == None, msg = "Office name can only start with a letter.")

def tearDown(self):
    self.office = None
```

And the results from the testcases

```
....(<room.Office object at 0x7fa84dc96a10>, <room.Office object at 0x7fa84dc968d0>)
```

F...

Comment: Throw an exception.

Comment: You can raise an exception when the name starts with a digit

Comment: is raising an exception the only solution?

Comment: @MeshackMbuvi no,you can prevent object creation with `__new__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading much, have got the answer.
During object creation, **new** is called before **init**.Thus by overriding **new** one can control object creation.
In my case, I want to create only rooms(offices) whose name start with a letter. This is what have done:

```
def __new__(cls,rname):

    '''We need this method since creation of an office object is depended on the first character of its name'''
    if not rname[0].isdigit():
        return Room.__new__(cls, rname)

    else:
        return None #don't create object here. __init__() is not called too.
```

Comment: bad solution, `exception` is much more better solution

Comment: But why is this a bad solution?

Comment: @AmphotericLewisAcid I would not say 'bad', I would say it is not nice in Python. Exceptions were designed for handling errors.

Comment: @AmphotericLewisAcid  If a `RoomNameStartsWithNumer` exception it thrown, it is very explicit and makes the code clear in both sides, in `__init__` and where the object is created. Much more clear to see `except RoomNameStartsWithNumer as err:`, than `if room_obj is None:`. What is more, you can return some message (e.g. the wrong room name) in the exception.

Comment: @AmphotericLewisAcid  Actually in C++ you can do similar (`new (nothrow)`), which returns a null pointer instead of throwing an exception. But C++ is about performance and returning a pointer is more performant in assembly, than rewinding the stack.
IMHO this solution very useful (I like it very much!), but not Pythonish.